# 1 to n relationship in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have an invoice model that i want it to have 'n' products in it so in my invoice model i place a relation hasMany like below

```
 public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product','id','product_id');
}
```

so in database of invoice i create 5 fields for products and a quantitiy for each of products

```
 $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('title');
        $table->longText('description');
        $table->integer('client_id');
        $table->integer('product_id1');
        $table->integer('product_quantity1');
        $table->integer('product_id2')->nullable();
        $table->integer('product_quantity2')->nullable();
        $table->integer('product_id3')->nullable();
        $table->integer('product_quantity3')->nullable();
        $table->integer('product_id4')->nullable();
        $table->integer('product_quantity4')->nullable();
        $table->integer('product_id5')->nullable();
        $table->integer('product_quantity5')->nullable();
```

i want to know is it the right way to do this or i should make a table contain the id of product and the id of invoice to combine them with each other ??? and if i have to make a new table how should i set the relations ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks similar to [Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) approach between invoice and products. Add a junction table (invoice_products) which connects invoice and products, table should have `invoice_id`, `product_id` , Also have pivot attribute for `quantity` for each product like

For many to many you can add definitions in your models like

```
class Invoice extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'invoice_products', 'invoice_id')
                    ->withPivot('quantity')
                    ->as('invoice_products_pivot');
    }
}


class Product extends Model
{
    public function invoices()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Invoice::class, 'invoice_products', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @M khalid Junaid thats my answer but just to be sure should i make a controller or maybe even model for invoice_products or just do the definitions and store them in invoice controller and handle the oporations from there ? thanks again

Comment: @Farshad No you don't need to define model for `invoice_products` just handle add/update operations of many to many using laravel helpers

Comment: Thanks khalid i got that i will try that .